# Can't translate some sentences

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I'm trying to translate "The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart". I already have the translation in the correct translation file:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/i18n/Language.csv
```

with:

```
"The requested qty exceeds the maximum qty allowed in shopping cart","Translation"
```

The other translations are working (didn't test all, but the ones i need are working).
The file that sets the message is:

```
/vendor/magento/module-inventory-sales/Model/IsProductSalableForRequestedQtyCondition/IsCorrectQtyCondition.php
```

I've logged all result to it with only one product in cart and it is accessed 7 times when reloading the page. Not sure it is supposed to.

Also tried to change to another phrase. Like __('January'). It displays without being translated. And in the 4 first accesses to the function it logs without translation but the last 3 it translates.

Could there be anything wrong with my setup? I'm not using the default theme. But i've run a grep to find that exact phrase only showing in the original file and when changed it changes the output. But never translates.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to debug and understand why it doesn't work you can try to debug `\Magento\Framework\Translate`

See `loadData` method

The order to load translation

```php
        // Load data from module translation files
        $this->_loadModuleTranslation();
        // Load translation dictionary from language packages
        $this->_loadPackTranslation();
        // Load current theme translation according to fallback
        $this->_loadThemeTranslation();
        // Loading current translation from DB
        $this->_loadDbTranslation();
```

Translate renderer (`\Magento\Framework\Phrase\Renderer\Translate::render`) uses `getData` for translate

First of all to be sure you have correct data in translation `\Magento\Framework\Translate::getData`

Comment: When i started to debug but changing the vendor/magento/framework/Translate.php, it started to work on the store view. Not sure why, because i always cleared cache and static files... Thank you for helping debug it.